# GeoServer WMS Layout File not Found

Tags: geoserver, layouts

I have a map containing two layers and I need to configure a decoration layout to include a scale line and the legend for one of the layers.

However, it seems that GeoServer can't find my layout file. In fact, when I go to the style preview page (on GeoServer), the map area shows nothing but an error message saying `Could not find decoration layout named: style-editor-legend` and here's what it looks like:

[image]

I have checked my "Data Directory" on the "Server Status" page and it points correctly to where my layout directory is, along with my layout file, so I suppose that's not the issue.

Is there a place where I can inform the layout file to be used? A GeoServer page or a file somewhere?

I do realize I must insert `&format_options=layout:style-editor-legend` to the request parameters, but, when I do that, the map that currently works (without the legend and scale line) stops working.

Here is my .js code that currently requests the map (shown after the code).

What am I getting wrong?

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-55.41, -15.82]),
        zoom: 4.5
    })
});

var mun_covid19 = new ol.layer.Image({
    source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
        url:'http://192.168.3.143:8080/geoserver/Covid19_Workspace/wms',
        params:{'layers':'Covid19_Workspace:municipios_covid19'},
        serverType: 'geoserver'
    })
});

map.addLayer(mun_covid19);

var brasil_estados = new ol.layer.Image({
    source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
        url:'http://192.168.3.143:8080/geoserver/Covid19_Workspace/wms',
        params:{'layers':'Covid19_Workspace:estados_brasileiros'},
        serverType: 'geoserver'
    })
});

map.addLayer(brasil_estados);
```

[image]

Comment: Your layout file should be in $DATA_DIR/layouts/style-editor-legend.xml and GeoServer must be able to read it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to update the Environment Variables (on Windows) in order to have GeoServer to locate the layout file.

The reason for that, I found, is that I had GeoServer installed a while ago with Apache/Tomcat, but later had to uninstall in order to re-install with XAMPP. That changed the directories used by GeoServer. In this condition, GeoServer did list the correct directory on the Server Status page, but the environment variables kept the previous values.

Updating the values solved my problem.

More details on https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/datadirectory/setting.html.

@IanTurt[on's comment reminde](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/362424/geoserver-wms-layout-file-not-found#comment592951_362424)d me of the mentioned page, which I had come across a while ago but failed to realize it had the solution I needed.

That being said, it might be useful for someone facing the same issue to know that GeoServer also returns that same error massage when there is an error in the contents of the layout file, such as a missing ">", for axample.